# How to compare data between 2 tables and insert differential in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables Table A and Table B. Both have same columns and datatypes but no primary key. All columns contains int values. I want to compare data between Table A and Table B and insert the differential  data into Table C. How can we do this?

```
create table a
(
col1 int, col2 int, col3 int
)
create table b
(
col1 int, col2 int, col3 int
)
insert into a values
(
2000,
1534,
4556
)

insert into b values
(
2000,
2345,
4118
)
```

I want a table c which shows difference of A and B as following
Table C output
0,
-811,
438

how can we achieve this?

Comment: Depemding on the version of SQL you are using (you never told us), you might be able to use `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @Aashi I've uipdated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated according to your question updates.
You can use row number to join and get difference between the columns.

```
SELECT t1.col1 - t2.col1 col1
      ,t1.col2 - t2.col2 col2
      ,t1.col3 - t2.col3 col3
from 
(select r1=ROW_NUMBER()over (order by col1),* from a) t1
 inner join (select r2=ROW_NUMBER()over (order by col1),* from b)t2
 on t1.r1=t2.r2
```